# Properly Configure IIS App Pool to Access Hardware

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, iis-8, user-accounts

I'm working with an ASP.net based web app that accesses some specialized hardware on the server by use of a DLL. The platform is Windows 8.1 with IIS, and notably this is *not* a server edition of Windows or a multi-client headless server type of application.

This worked fine in IIS Express when testing in Visual Studio, but doesn't work in actual IIS.

As far as I can tell, the ApplicationPoolIdentity account has very few privileges and can't access the hardware. By changing the application pool's identity to LocalSystem or to the (admin) user account, I could get it to work fine, but those are both clearly terrible options from a security standpoint.

Most information I can find about access controls in this context is focused around access to files, not to hardware devices.

How should one approach this?